# Sorting a CSV file from greatest to least based a number appearing in a column

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a CSV file like this:

```
bear,1
fish,20
tiger,4
```

I need to sort it from greatest to least number, based on what is found in the second column, e.g.:

```
fish,20
tiger,4
bear,1
```

How can the file be sorted in this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sort -t, -k+2 -n -r filename
```

will do what you want.

`-t,` specifies the field separator to be a comma

`-k+2` specifies the field to sort on (field2)

`-r` specifies a reverse sort

`-n` specifies a numeric sort

Comment: i came up with `sort -t , -k 2 -n -r test.txt`...+1

Comment: you might want to slap a link to the man page.  There is an almost exact example at the bottom of http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html.  My bash-fu is extremely weak, but I was able to do it.